# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol? I'm absolutely lost

Tags: visual-c++, external, symbols, lnk2001

I am new to C++ and I have been practicing by translating my old Java code into c++. I have come across so many errors that I almost gave up hope. I'm also trying to fix an error in the main file, I'm trying to call a function in the main file, but I'm get syntax errors like crazy and I dont know whats wrong. I've tried googling and searching for weeks on how to fix these errors in main.cpp. I appreciated the help if you can.

```
// NamedStorm.cpp 
// CPP=> Function definition
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "NamedStorm.h"
using namespace std;

// Makes sure that the displayOutput method work properly
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const NamedStorm& namedStorm);

// Default Constructor definition (removed parameter due to issues)
NamedStorm::NamedStorm(){

}

// Overload construtor definition
NamedStorm::NamedStorm(string sName, double wSpeed, string sCat,double sPress){
    stormName = sName;
    stormCategory = sCat;
    stormPressure = sPress;
    stormCount++;
}
// Destructor definition
NamedStorm::~NamedStorm(){}

// Accessor function definition
void NamedStorm::displayOutput(NamedStorm storm[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(storm); i++){
        cout << storm[i] << "\n";
    }
}

void NamedStorm::sortByNames(NamedStorm storm[]){
    cout << "Sorting array in decsending alphabetical order by names..." << endl;
    for(int k = 1; k < 4; k++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4 - k; i++){
            if((storm[i].getName()).compare(storm[i+1].getName()) > 0){
                NamedStorm temp;
                temp = storm[i];
                storm[i] = storm[i+1];
                storm[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void NamedStorm::getAverageWindSpeed(NamedStorm storm[]){
    double averageWSpeed = 0.0;
    double totalWindSpeed = 0.0;

    totalWindSpeed = storm[0].maxWindSpeed
        + storm[1].maxWindSpeed + storm[2].maxWindSpeed + storm[3].maxWindSpeed
        + storm[4].maxWindSpeed;

    averageWSpeed = totalWindSpeed / sizeof(storm);
    cout << "The average max wind speeds of storms: " << averageWSpeed << "mph"<< endl;
}

void NamedStorm::getAverageStormPressure(NamedStorm storm[]){
    double averageSPress = 0.0;
    double totalStormPressure = 0.0;

    totalStormPressure = storm[0].getStormPressure()
        + storm[1].getStormPressure() + storm[2].getStormPressure() + storm[3].getStormPressure()
        + storm[4].getStormPressure();

    averageSPress = totalStormPressure / 5;
    cout << "The Average storm pressure: " << averageSPress << " mb" << endl;
}

int NamedStorm::getStormCount(){
    return stormCount;
}

double NamedStorm::getStormPressure(){
    return stormPressure;
}

double NamedStorm::getWindSpeed(){
    return maxWindSpeed;
}

string NamedStorm::getStormCategory(){
    return stormCategory;
}

string NamedStorm::getName(){
    return stormName;
}


// Mutator function definition
```

//NamedStorm.h

```
// Header => Function Declaration
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef NAMEDSTORM_H
#define NAMEDSTORM_H

class NamedStorm{
public:
    // Default constructor declaration
    NamedStorm();

    // Overloaded constructor declaration
    NamedStorm(string, double, string, double);

    // Destructor declaration
    ~NamedStorm();

    // Accessor (GET methods in Java) functions declarations (will return variables), use const, when not changing member variables
    static void displayOutput(NamedStorm storm[]);
    static void sortByNames(NamedStorm storm[]);
    static void sortByWindSpeed(NamedStorm storm[]);
    static void getAverageWindSpeed(NamedStorm storm[]);
    static void getAverageStormPressure(NamedStorm storm[]);
    int getStormCount();
    double getStormPressure();
    double getWindSpeed();
    string getStormCategory();
    string getName();

    // Mutator functions (SET methods in Javinese)
    void setStormName();
    void setStormCategory();
    void setMaxWindSpeed();
    void setStormPressure();

private:
    string stormName;
    string stormCategory;
    double maxWindSpeed;
    double stormPressure;
    static int stormCount;
};
```

// Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "NamedStorm.h"

using namespace std;

NamedStorm storm[5];

int main(){
    NamedStorm Chris("Chris", 70, "Tropical Storm", 990);
    NamedStorm Alberto("Alberto", 45, "Tropical Storm", 1007);
    NamedStorm Gordon("Gordon", 65, "Tropical Storm", 999);
    NamedStorm Isaac("Isaac", 80, "1", 969);
    NamedStorm Ernesto("Ernesto", 50, "Tropical Storm", 1006);

    storm[0] = Alberto;
    storm[1] = Chris;
    storm[2] = Ernesto;
    storm[3] = Gordon;
    storm[4] = Isaac;

    // Error: identifier not found
    displayOutput();
    sortByNames();
    displayOutput();
    sortByWindSpeed();
    displayOutput();
    getAverageStormPressure();
    getAverageWindSpeed();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok the LNK2001 error isnt appearing anymore, now its just the "identifier not found" errors on the calling functions in main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest breaking it down into smaller chunks (commenting everything out) and adding items back in one at a time - making sure you understand each as you go.

On the "identifier not found", it looks like you're trying to call a static class method but it's not prefixed with the name of the class. I think instead of:

```
displayOutput();
```

in main(), you want:

```
NamedStorm::displayOutput();
```

but even that's not quite right because the method takes a storm array and no parameters are being supplied. So I think the correct signature would be:

```
NamedStorm stormArray[2];
NamedStorm::displayOutput( stormArray );
```

If the intention was to call a global "displayOutput()", I don't see one defined so that would account for the error message in that case.

PART II - ostream operator ==============================================================

Ugh... you really are starting at the top! OK, I couldn't get it to work either - I looked at all these links about how to correctly defined templates, etc. ... but the problem is exactly as simple as the error message. The reference is unresolved because it doesn't exist! You defined a new operator, but didn't provide an implementation. All you need is to provide the implementation, like so:

```
// this declares the operator, but it's still undefined
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const NamedStorm& namedStorm);

// add this to *define* it - otherwise it has no body so the linker looks in all the
// obj files, can't find it and gives the unresolved reference error
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const NamedStorm& namedStorm)
{
//print("we needed an implementation!");
return out;
}
```

Now, in practice you don't need a declaration immediately followed by the implementation, but normally the declaration would go in a .h file OR there would be no declaration at all, you could just have the implementation above in your .CPP file. But no other source files would know about it.

It's generally considered poor practice to pepper the project with the:

```
using namespace std;
```

Instead, be more explicit with which namespace you want, eg:

```
std::string myString = "we know which 'string' this is";
```

Seems easier to just say "using everything..." until you spend half a day tracking down a bug only to realize you weren't even looking at the right class!

Whew..I rest now ;-)

Comment: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int NamedStorm::stormCount" (?stormCount@NamedStorm@@0HA) . Maybe its the private variables?

Comment: It's not that "stormCount" is private, that's OK because you're referring to it from inside the class. The problem here is that it's static, but you're trying to refer to it from the constructor, which is an instance method. It should work fine if you say "NamedStorm::stormCount++" inside the constructor. (may want to decrement it as well in the destructor - dunno depends on your needs). Glad it's working for you.

Comment: I decided to remove the static (still want it in though, maybe I dont need it) now all im left is this very strange error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream...DADADDADADADADADAD

Comment: Yeah I got lost on what you said and decided to call it quits until I get the basics. Do you recommend any free C++ (or paid) for newbies?